# Iterating through JSON and adding to array, but preventing multiple additions to the array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-datepicker

What is the best way of iterating through a JSON response, and inserting specific elements of the JSON element into an array (assuming I'm using React hooks). This is my attempt, but the issue is the first time I execute the function, I get no output, the second time, I get the intended output, and then the consequent executions keep on adding to the datelist array(size doubles every time).

```
const get = () => {
    fetch('/test')  
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {setDates(data)})
    setDatelist([]);
    setDatelist(datelist => [...datelist, dates.map(date => date.start["dateTime"])]);
    console.log(datelist);  
}
```

Comment: I fixed the issue of doubling by resetting the datelist to an empty array before running the map function. I still run the issue where the first function execution doesn't give me an output, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is the `useEffect` hook, [document](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#conditionally-firing-an-effect). It can subscribe to a React state or props change.

Essentially, your code should be split into several parts, something like this:

```js
// 1. I assume you have a state to maintain `dates`
const [dates, setDates] = useState([]);

const get = () => {
    fetch('/test')  
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {setDates(data)}) 
// 2. here you call `setDates` to update the state, from your description it should be working already
}

useEffect(() => {
// 3. in useEffect hook, you can subscribe to `dates` change, and do whatever you need to do here once the dependency is updated
// below is something I copied from your question, please change it based on your need
  setDatelist(datelist => [...datelist, dates.map(date => date.start["dateTime"])]);
  console.log(datelist); 
}, [dates]);
```

Hope this can help, please comment if you need more information.